# How do I design a native looking OS X application preferences with Qt?

Tags: qt

Other than trying to manually, re-write everything to mimic the tooblar graphics and the size transition animation when moving between pages, Is there a better way to do this?

Amazingly I can't find ANY resources covering this, or even someone asking for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtwidgets-index.html#styles

The window animations may already work as is... You may want to specify Native Windowing, so that the Mac Windowing system is aware of your Qt windows:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets

> ### Native Widgets vs Alien Widgets
>
> Introduced in Qt 4.4, alien widgets
>   are widgets unknown to the windowing system. They do not have a native
>   window handle associated with them. This feature significantly speeds
>   up widget painting, resizing, and removes flicker. Should you require
>   the old behavior with native windows, you can choose one of the
>   following options:
>
> 1. Use the `QT_USE_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1` in your
>      environment.
> 2. Set the Qt::AA_NativeWindows attribute on your
>      application. All widgets will be native widgets.
> 3. Set the
>      Qt::WA_NativeWindow attribute on widgets: The widget itself and all of
>      its ancestors will become native (unless
>      Qt::WA_DontCreateNativeAncestors is set).
> 4. Call QWidget::winId to
>      enforce a native window (this implies 3).
> 5. Set the Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen
>      attribute to enforce a native window (this implies 3).
>
> See also
>   QEvent, QPainter, QGridLayout, and QBoxLayout.

And this link has more information on the styling in Qt than I have ever seen before today!

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/style-reference.html

Hope that helps.